# Adding Angular 7 chips for mat-slide-toggle buttons when they are On state

Tags: angular

On toggle of starter chip should be added to simocode li

```
<mat-tab label="Device" >
        <ul>
            <mat-slide-toggle (change)="onChange($event)" >
            <!--li for chips-->
            <li>Simocode</li>
            </mat- `enter code here`
            slide-toggle>
            <mat-slide-toggle>
                <li>starter</li>
            </mat-slide-toggle>
        </ul>
    </mat-tab>
```

Comment: Could you please explain the issue?

Comment: explain bit about what you want

Comment: Like if i toggle on the mat-slide-toggle (text:starter) .starter text should be added as angular chip in another line                                                                                           <mat-slide-toggle>
                <li>starter</li>
            </mat-slide-toggle>        starter should appear as angular material chip if  the toggle is in ON state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is on toggle `active` you need to add the chip with text 'Starter' and on toggle `inactive` you need to remove the chip.

Here is the code for template

```
  <mat-slide-toggle (change)="onToggle($event)"> Starter </mat-slide-toggle>
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let chip of chips">{{chip}}</mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
```

And in your component.

```
export class AppComponent {
  chips: any = [];

  onToggle(event) {
    let { checked } = event;
    const text = event.source._elementRef.nativeElement.innerText;
    if(checked) {
      this.chips.push(text);
    } else {
      let index = this.chips.indexOf(text);
      this.chips = this.chips.slice(1, index);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-km8zpp) example

Comment: This code works .but when there are too many <mat-slide-toggle ></mat-slide-toggle>  in a popup and when i close the popup the changes to the mat-slide-toggle are getting reset.Can you please help on this?

Comment: Have updated the example to work with modal and persist the state of <mat-slide-toggle> 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-km8zpp